# Creating Arrays in numpy using zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, zero

I've been trying to create a 6 by 6 array in python using the numpy module with all elements set as 0.0:

```
import numpy as np
RawScores = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.float)
print RawScores
```

This outputs:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Why are there no commas? Is it still an array without them?

Comment: That's just the way `numpy` *displays* it - try `type(RawScores)` to check that it is what you think it is.

Comment: print type(RawScores) resulted in an output of <type 'numpy.ndarray'> , so I assume this means it must be an array, so it's ok there are no commas! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `print` function calls the `__str__` method, instead of the `__repr__` method. See the following example. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for a detailed explanation of the difference between these two methods.

```
# Python 2D List
>>> [[0]*6]*6
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros((6,6))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

# calls __repr__
>>> a = np.zeros((6,6))
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

# calls __str__
>>> print a
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really really care about the commas you can always redefine the way numpy prints out arrays, VERY dirty example:

```
import numpy as np
RawScores = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.float)
def add_comma(num):
  return "%g, " % num

np.set_printoptions(formatter={"all":add_comma})
print RawScores
[[0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, ]    
 [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, ]
 [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, ]
 [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, ]
 [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, ]
 [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, ]]
```